# Why won't Revival badges be awarded on closed questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

The FAQ on meta.SO says [about closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question):

> When a question is closed, no additional answers may be posted to it,
>   although the question and existing answers can still be edited (by
>   users with edit privileges) and voted upon, and will continue to count
>   for badges.

I've noticed it when I saw the confirmation on: [Will Reversal badge be awarded on closed questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28891/will-reversal-badge-be-awarded-on-closed-questions)

Now I considered the same for the [Revival badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/62/revival). Somebody could say: why to revive closed questions? However, the question must have been revived before closing of course. And as "reversing" counts, and the counter works for nice answer, great answer, etc. I don't see why reviving should be ignored, I guess there's something missing. I found two closed questions, where answers qualify for Revival badges but did not get it.

- [The entire table is not displayed even when rotating package is used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26433/the-entire-table-is-not-displayed-even-when-rotating-package-is-used/30184)
- [Problem related to “hpdftex.pdf”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22683/problem-related-to-hpdftex-pdf)

This seems to be inconsistent, seen the FAQ and other badges. It would be great if that would be checked. As the Necromancer badge is related, it might be good to check this one as well. I post this question here on TeX.SX because I don't know if the effect has been seen on other SE sites.

Comment: I know the usual reasons for missing badges, such as being invalidated by deleting or downvoting. I assume it won't be the case here, as just minutes before the first linked question qualified, I got a badge for another one. I noticed it since in "answer the unanswered" sessions we usually try answering old questions, so revivals can happen by the way. The two questions happened in such answering chat sessions.

Comment: Why are you answering closed questions? This sends a very bad message to the community -- as in "we the moderators are privileged enough to answer a question and then close it, but you are not". There have been many complaints about this on meta.so historically and I strongly urge you to not engage in this negative behavior.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: I answered open questions, never a closed one. Another one later decided to close it which I did not foresee.

Comment: ah I see -- sorry for the misunderstanding, that is fine then. However the "answer then close by same user" (when it happens..) breeds a lot of discontent...

Comment: @JeffAtwood: No problem. And I understand that. One should not answer and then prevent others from answering. Also, who answers shows his opinion that the question *can* be answered, no need to close. I wasn't very satisfied with the closing too, since we made an "Answering chat session", not a closing session ;-) however in the very active session somebody else decided to close a bit later, which I respected.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: If they should be an exception to the rule, that closed questions still count for badges, it should me mentioned in the badge description. Though any time it could happen that somebody, who seeked out an old unanswered question and made an effort in contributing an answer, could think "they closed and stole my revival badge, I can see the upvotes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an explicit "is not closed" check on this badge, I'm not sure of the historical reason, there may not have even been one.  It's a *very* low impact change (only 5 haven't been awarded because of this on Stack Overflow), so we're making it.

In the next build we'll start awarding revival for closed questions.

Note: we did look at necromancer as well to be sure, it has no closed check, so no change there.